# How to eliminate NULL values in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  `date`,
  MAX(IF(`index_name` = 'Alerian MLP PR USD' AND `time_period`='M1', results, NULL)) AS `Alerian MLP PR USD`,
  MAX(IF(`index_name` = 'MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD' AND `time_period`='M1', results, NULL)) AS `MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD`
FROM
  `mst_ind`
GROUP BY `date`
```

The problem is that it returns multiple NULL values like

[image]

I could wrap that query inside another query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  `date`,
  MAX(IF(`index_name` = 'Alerian MLP PR USD' AND `time_period`='M1', results, NULL)) AS `Alerian MLP PR USD`,
  MAX(IF(`index_name` = 'MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD' AND `time_period`='M1', results, NULL)) AS `MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD`
FROM
  `mst_ind`
GROUP BY `date`
) sel
WHERE sel.`MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD` IS NOT NULL AND sel.'Alerian MLP PR USD' IS NOT NULL
```

But it is not a nice solution, because I will have to list all fields in the "NOT NULL" clause.

Is there a more simple way of eliminating NULL values here?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to see instead of `NULL`s?

Comment: Something shorter than a string of 30 "NOT NULL" fields.

Comment: I mean what do you want to see in the resultset, not in your query. In your current query you filter out all rows that have values for `MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD` index just because you don't have values for `Alerian MLP PR USD` index on those dates. Is this a desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry, did't understand your question first. Yes, exactly. I don't need any NULL vales, if there are no index values for that date. I can get a desired outcome, if I list all fields in WHERE clause "NOT NULL". Too long query string though.